# In date_sun_info() what is Transit

Tags: php

I understand the meaning of Sun Transit to be the time it takes for the sun to move from the sunrise position to the sunset position however [date_sun_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php) transit seems to return the midpoint in the day where the sun is exactly between the sunrise and sunset position.

```
$sun_info = date_sun_info(strtotime("2006-12-12"), 31.7667, 35.2333);
foreach ($sun_info as $key => $val) {
 echo "$key: " . date("H:i:s", $val) . "\n";
}
```

The above example will output:

> sunrise: 05:52:11
>   sunset: 15:41:21
>   transit: 10:46:46
>   civil_twilight_begin: 05:24:08
>   civil_twilight_end: 16:09:24
>   nautical_twilight_begin: 04:52:25
>   nautical_twilight_end: 16:41:06
>   astronomical_twilight_begin: 04:21:32
>   astronomical_twilight_end: 17:12:00

Comment: +1 just because I didn't know this function existed. What won't PHP wrap into a built-in function?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, it isn't. See my answer :)

Comment: My bad @vascowhite! :) As an amateur astronomer we often refer to transit as something completely different. I was unaware that solar transit referred to something else! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_transit_time) is the time that the sun passes over the observer's [meridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography)). So it is midday by a sundial at the longitude you happen to be at. Clock midday and solar midday are often quite different and I suspect the time given is UTC, although that is a guess as it is not explained in the manual and I would expect [this](http://3v4l.org/boVQh) to give a result nearer to 12:00, although I haven't had time to check the calculation properly.

<strike>It may be that the person who wrote this function did not understand the term 'transit' just as the person who wrote the date_sunrise() and date_sunset() functions [did not understand the term 'zenith'](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62548).</strike>